# Декабря месяца

Tags: стилистика

По-прежнему ли считается избыточным употребление слова "месяца", например, во фразе "в течение декабря месяца"?

Comment: Да. Избыточно.
.............

Comment: Отдает унылым канцеляризмом.

Answer (score 1):

Такие выражения называются плеоназмом и так же нежелательны, как "каждая минута времени, своя автобиография, впервые знакомиться, неожиданный сюрприз, сувенир на память, местный абориген, первая премьера, свободная вакансия " и т.д.

Comment: И все равно такие выражения жили и жить будут. Видимо, они отражают какую-то потребность человека. В конце концов, некоторая избыточность кода - не такой уж недостаток, она имеет и свои плюсы.  

Вот например, если эти выражения напишет @behemothus и забудет проверить опечатки, мы все равно сможем восстановить смысл ;-))  

Вообще лингвистическая психология - наверное, интересная наука. Интересно, здесь с нею кто-нибудь знаком?

Comment: Почему и спросила "по-прежнему". Сейчас, по-моему, это уже стало устойчивым выражением )

Comment: Вы спросили "считается ли избыточным" - конечно, считается. А говорят или не говорят - это другое. И устойчивое выражение может содержать избыточную информацию.  

Лично мне это выражение не нравится, в отличие от некоторых других, приведенных @виктор1799. Скажем "впервые знакомиться": "Молодой человек очень смущался, он впервые знакомился с девушкой". Тут избыточности нет.  

В других примерах плеоназм не бросается в глаза из-за того, что основные существительные не переведены и не калькированы, так что повторяющийся смысл не бросается в глаза. Но то, что декабрь - месяц, знают все.

Answer (score -1):

Избыточно, но не "по-прежнему"* :-), и, наверное, не во всех стилях.

Думаю, как раз в начале распространения фразы, уточнение "месяц" вовсе не было лишним. А потом, когда весь народ выучил новые названия месяцев, стало избыточным.

А в самом консервативном сегменте речи - юридических и финансовых документах - так до сих пор и пишут: "в декабре месяце". Но там сложно оценить "неправильность", так как можно ведь рассматривать подобные выражения и чем-то вроде профессиональных терминов.

---

Это *по-прежнему* отдаёт какой-то логической диверсией в стиле Карлсона ("Ты *перестала* пить по утрам коньяк?").

---

behemothus, когда было начало, не знаю.

Comment: >Думаю, как раз в начале распространения фразы, уточнение "месяц" вовсе не было лишним.

Когда оно было, это начало?

Comment: А! Не знаете, когда было начало, но на него ссылаетесь?
Минус, г-н grumant.